# Does Play framework 2.2.3 support LESS in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

Am learning Play Framework, and i have write a small app in scala. and added some .less file which are not compiled.

the app is from the book's app sample github.com/andypetrella/play2-book-chapters/tree/master/chap3

So does Play framework in Scala support less and how to go about adding them(.less) in application? or is it the same as for java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .less files need to be in the app/assets/stylesheets folder. The LESS will be automatically compiled, but only when they are in that folder.

Comment: Thanks.... I have it on that path but the compiled css is'nt in public/stylsheets instead it is somewhere in Target folder

Comment: Yup, that is true. All compiled code gets outputted to the target folder.